# Reading file PHP using too much memory

Tags: php, file, memory

So, I'm trying to parse a text file that has 24MB and 314134 lines. The problem is, I feel like my script is using way too much memory.

This is the code:

```
if(file_exists($filePath)) {
            $data = file_get_contents($filePath);

            $lines = explode("\n", $data);
            foreach ($lines as $line) {
                //Split the line.
                $spllitedLine = explode(';', utf8_encode($line));

                //Get the fields by their index.
                $localidade = !empty($spllitedLine[3]) ? $spllitedLine[3] : '';
                $codigo_postal = $spllitedLine[14] . '-' . $spllitedLine[15];

                $morada = (!empty($spllitedLine[5]) ? $spllitedLine[5] : ' ') . ' ' .
                    (!empty($spllitedLine[6]) ? $spllitedLine[6] : ' ') . ' ' .
                    (!empty($spllitedLine[7]) ? $spllitedLine[7] : ' ') . ' ' .
                    (!empty($spllitedLine[8]) ? $spllitedLine[8] : ' ') . ' ' .
                    (!empty($spllitedLine[9]) ? $spllitedLine[9] : '');

                //Create a new CTT location and save it to the Database.
                $location = new CttLocations();
                $location->address = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $morada);
                $location->location = $localidade;
                $location->zipcode = $codigo_postal;
                $location->save(false);

                //Unset the variables to free space.
                unset($location);
                unset($line);
                unset($morada);
            }
        }
```

This is currently using 153MB of memory and it's not even in the half of the file. I've read that using `fopen()` `fgets()` and `fclose()` it's a better solution but I was using roughly the same amount of memory with those methods. What am I doing wrong? I thought by unsetting the variables I would free some much needed space. I think 150MB is WAY too much for an operation like this. Any thouhgts?

Comment: It is file I/O which can be and is really expensive.

Comment: My guess would be additional overhead by PHP and the explode statement. You store every line of the contents in an array. So thats 2x 24MB + overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This :

```
 $data = file_get_contents($filePath);
```

Is way to heavy for big files.

This is how you read a file line by line :

```
$handle = fopen("inputfile.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        // process the line read.
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```